# VB.NET Listview grouping

Tags: vb.net, listview, grouping

I try to raggrup a list in a listview object for the first letter of the film title .

I found a code working on the internet from which I was inspired to change my code.
In debugging I see correctly assigned group represented by the initial letter (I have grouped everything that does not start with a letter, with the character "#").
In the form that contains the listview object, the list is not grouped and I do not understand why.

Thanks a lot for any advice.

This is the code I wrote

```
        lvFilmDetail.BeginUpdate()
        lvFilmDetail.Items.Clear()

        Dim ws_firstLetter_svd As Char = ""
        Dim ctr_group As Integer = -1
        For Each ws_film In ws_elenco_film
            Dim item As New ListViewItem(ws_film.Get_Titolo)

            CreateGroup(ws_film.Get_Titolo, ws_firstLetter_svd, item)

            lvFilmDetail.Items.Add(item)

        Next

        lvFilmDetail.Columns.Item(4).Width = 0

        lvFilmDetail.EndUpdate()

    End If


End Sub

Private Sub CreateGroup(ByVal ws_title As String, ByRef ws_firstLetter_svd As Char, ByRef item As ListViewItem)
    Dim ws_firstLetter As Char
    ws_firstLetter = ws_title
    Dim lvFilmDetailGroup As ListViewGroup

    Select Case Asc(ws_firstLetter)
        Case < 65
            ws_firstLetter = "#"
        Case > 122
            ws_firstLetter = "#"
        Case 91 To 96
            ws_firstLetter = "#"
    End Select

    If ws_firstLetter <> ws_firstLetter_svd Then

        lvFilmDetailGroup = New ListViewGroup(ws_firstLetter)
        lvFilmDetail.Groups.Add(lvFilmDetailGroup)
    End If

    item.Group = lvFilmDetailGroup

End Sub
```

I compared the properties of the listview in my project and in the example and I did not find any differences, with the exception of the grid and the presence of a contextual menu that in the example is not present

These are the the screenshots of my program and the example:

Grouping error:
[image: Grouping Error]

Grouping example:
[image: Grouping Example]

This is my code after a few changes, I continue to have the same problem:

```
        Dim lvFilmDetailGroup As ListViewGroup
        Dim ws_firstLetter As Char = ""
        Dim ws_firstLetter_svd As Char
        Dim ctr_group As Integer = -1
        For Each ws_film In ws_elenco_film

            ws_firstLetter = ws_film.Get_Titolo
            Select Case Asc(ws_firstLetter)
                Case < 65
                    ws_firstLetter = "#"
                Case > 122
                    ws_firstLetter = "#"
                Case 91 To 96
                    ws_firstLetter = "#"
            End Select

            If ws_firstLetter <> ws_firstLetter_svd Then
                '$$$ accorpare caratteri diversi dalle lettere
                ctr_group += 1

                lvFilmDetailGroup = New ListViewGroup(ctr_group.ToString, ws_firstLetter)
                lvFilmDetail.Groups.Add(lvFilmDetailGroup)

                ws_firstLetter_svd = ws_firstLetter
            End If

            Dim item As New ListViewItem(ws_film.Get_Titolo)
            item.Group = lvFilmDetailGroup

            lvFilmDetail.Items.Add(item)

        Next

        lvFilmDetail.Columns.Item(4).Width = 0

        lvFilmDetail.EndUpdate()

    End If
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? What do you mean by 'is not grouped'? Is your listview style possibly incorrect?

Comment: I have updated the post with two images. Thanks

Comment: What are your 'ShowGroups' and 'View' properties on the ListView set to?

Comment: ShowGroups is "True" and View is "Details".

Comment: Do you ever reach this statement: 'lvFilmDetailGroup = New ListViewGroup(ws_firstLetter)' ?

Comment: Yes. it's in the code at any changes of "ws_firstletter"

Comment: When these two (ws_firstLetter <> ws_firstLetter_svd ) are equal how to you get the group ?

Comment: When firstletter doesn't change, i using the last object created in the 
previous round. 
I think there was still an error, the variable "Dim lvFilmDetailGroup As ListViewGroup" was defined within the sub "CreateGroup" and was redefined every time.
I have moved all the code in the main loop, but nothing is not dealt with

Comment: You might update the question with your latest code, for anyone else looking at this. I'm stumped. I've copied your code, with minor changes, and it works for me.

Comment: How can I export in a txt file the property of listview?

Comment: I've copied your new code and that works too. The only way I've managed to get this to fail is to force the view to 'list' at the end.         lvFilmDetail.View = View.List . Are you 100% by the end of your loop that the View is 'Details' ?

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding why it does not work ... I've created a new application to test the Listview object. Everything is working correctly, but by bringing the form into my project I got the same result as before.
I focused on defining the assembly of my program and I realized that the problem is that I started it from the Sub Main (disabling the application framework). If I start the application directly from the test form and enable the framework, everything works.
My problem, now, is to enable the framework during the execution of the program in order not to overturn the starting logic

Comment: SOLVED!! I have added in the main procedure this statement before run form: Application.EnableVisualStyles() - Thanks a lot for your advice!!

Comment: After you find the group you want, you can iterate through its Items collection.

Comment: Hi Andrew, can you write your advice as an answer? I cannot accept a solution if it's only a comment. Thank you. Marcello

Comment: Oh I don't think I did resolve this. You did the hard work and found the solution yourself in the end. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solved!! I have added in the main procedure this statement before run form: Application.EnableVisualStyles().
with this code I see the grouping.